# Load remote form in rails 3 with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I am new in rails and javascript. This may be a very simple question but I am still unable to figure it out. 
The goal is that, I have a link to button that when clicked should load a address form on the same page. The link to code is

> <%= link_to "Add Address", new_address_path, {:class => "button"}, {:remote => true} %>

The address file "addresses/new.html.erb" is:

```
<div id="newaddr">
  <%= render :partial => 'form', :local => @address %>
</div>
```

The form is "addresses/_form.html.erb":

```
<%= form_for(@address, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <%= f.text_field :line_1 %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The javascript file "addresses/new.js.erb":

```
$('#newaddr').append("<%= escape_javaScript(render 'form', :local => @address) %>");
```

The new method in addresses_controller file is:

```
def new
  @title = "Add Address"
  @address = Address.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. Is there anything I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you get? If it's a javascript issue and you are using firefox I suggest to use firebug to debug ajax requests.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you included the necessary javascript libraries? <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> in your layout?

Comment: The error I get is  Started GET "/addresses/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-02 08:29:34 -0500
  Processing by AddressesController#new as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 13ms

Comment: I did add the javascript libraries through gem 'jquery-rails' and rails g jquery:install --ui

Answer (score 0):

The error you get indicates that your link is being executed as a normal HTML link, not a js. Your controller method only accepts the js, so it returns the 406, not acceptable.

The most obvious reason for this is that the `rails.js` javascript is not included in your `application.html.erb`. Normally adding the following line is sufficient:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :default %>
```

or, if that does not work, do it explicitly:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min.js', 'jquery-ui.min.js', 'rails.js' %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Change your new.js.erb file:

```
$('#newaddr').append("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :local => @address)}");
```